# sqlsrv connection string not valid [87]

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, wamp

Set up:

- Wamp Server
- PHP 5.5.12
- Apache 2.4.9
- MS SQL Server 2012

Already completed:

- Installed (unofficial) **php_sqlsrv_55_ts** and **php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts** AND confirmed they are working via phpinfo() [sqlsrv_link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e1d37219-88a3-46b2-a421-73bfa33fe433/unofficial-php-55-drivers-x86)
- I have made sure that TCP/IP is enabled in SQL Configuration Manager
- I have tested credentials in SQL Management Studio AND via ODBC in Administrrative Tools
- IIS is disabled

Additionally, I did have trouble with SQL Reporting Service taking port 80. This was giving me a problem with Apache, so I directed SQL Reporting Service to use port 8081.

```
<?php
$server = "computer_name\MSSQLSERVER";
$user = "sa";
$pass = "password";
$db = "pcm";
$connInfo = array("Database"=>$db, "UID"=>$user, "PWD"=>$pass);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connInfo) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
?>
```

Comment: your ``\`` in the $server is probably getting parsed out. try `comp\\server` instead (two backslashes). Plus, don't use the SA account for this kind of thing. having that account open/accessible is a massive security risk.

Comment: Just tried two backslashes, but I got the same error. I've resulted in using the sa account for testing purposes because I haven't been able to get this thing to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the PDO extension, you will have to use a PDO connection instead of the `sqlsrv_connect()` function. Microsoft doesn't support the `UID` or `PWD` keys that you are providing when trying to connect via the PDO extension. Try this instead:

```
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server = ' . $server . '; Database = ' . $db, $user, $pass);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php